# Continuous deployment to many servers

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, gulp

I have a somewhat unique scenario where when I gulp my Node.js project, I want to deploy it on an arbitrary number of Linux servers. It might be 1 or 2 or 100.
How to create a gulp task to copy the project files to the servers? I am specifying machine addresses in an array in my gulpfile.js and then iterating that array to create the gulp tasks. That part works well, I'm just looking for what to use in the gulp task or another method altogether if you've got any ideas.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432331/how-to-use-gulp-to-run-a-remote-node-js-app where I'm asking about how to launch the Node.js process on the server once it's been copied.